# Adjust caption length to table length in hvFloat environment

Tags: tables, floats, captions

I am trying to create a sideways-table with multi-columns. As I want title and table on the same page, I am using the hvfloat package. I'd like to get a caption that is as wide as my table, but it seems as if the `hvfloat` package does not adjust caption/font size to the table size (as LaTeX does within the "regular" (not using `hvfloat`) table environment using the option `\caption{...}`

I had a look at the package `pdf` and figured that I have to set the length of the caption (?) by using `\setlength{}`. However, whatever I tried, it would not work.

Is there someone who can help me? 
Thanks a lot!

Simple working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,apa]{article}

\usepackage{hvFloat}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\hvFloat[%
nonFloat=true,%
capPos=l,%
capAngle=90,%
objectAngle=90,%
    ]{table}{\tiny%
\begin{tabular}{l cccc}
\toprule
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{XY} \\[0.5ex]
\midrule
         & wklrewkwrelwer & werwerwerwer z & werwerwrewera & wrewerwerwerb \\[1ex]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}%
[]{%
abcdefghijk lmnopq rzstuvwabcdefk gheow9kdsl slwowolslsllsl slslslls}{tab:3}
%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the option `capWidth=h` to the settings of your `\hvFloat`.

Since you have your table placed vertically, you have to specify `h`, that stands for the height of the float. Use `capWidth=w` (`w` is for width) when your table is placed horizontally, instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\hvFloat[%
nonFloat=true,%
capPos=l,%
capWidth=h,%
capAngle=90,%
objectAngle=90,%
    ]{table}{\tiny%
\begin{tabular}{l cccc}
\toprule
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{XY} \\[0.5ex]
\midrule
         & wklrewkwrelwer & werwerwerwer z & werwerwrewera & wrewerwerwerb \\[1ex]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}%
[]{%
abcdefghijk lmnopq rzstuvwabcdefk gheow9kdsl slwowolslsllsl slslslls}{tab:3}
%


\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: the name of the package is `hvfloat` while the name of the environment is `hvFloat`.